# New virtualized windows server with 4 partitions

Tags: vmware-vmdk

i'm going to set up a new Windows Server 2008R2 on vmware and it will be composed of 4 partitions: in order to have the best performance and manageability do you think that it's better to create a single "big" vmdk file that will contain the partitions or should i create a virtual disk for each of them?
What kind of vmware controller should i use? Can be the paravirtual Scsi a nice choice? The storage is now composed of a 10k SAS raid but the virtual machine will sooon be moved to a Storewize V7000.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more arrays in your storage (presented to VMWare as separate storages) and use four separate disks than SDRS can move your disks to separate arrays and this way IO performance will be better.

Also if your backup solution works on VMDKs then the performance penalty and the difficulty to be able to make consistent backups (flush and freeze the filesystem) will be more easy.

So I would use four separate VMDKs.